# the import java.util.scanner cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and programming and am following Derek Banas' tutorials on YouTube. This is my code thus far and I am getting an error saying "the import `java.util.scanner` cannot be resolved."

I have compiler compliance level 1.7 and JRE 1.8.0_25.

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class Javalesson2 {  

}
```

Comment: [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scanner is a Java class. All classes in Java should start with a capital letter.

Change

```
java.util.scanner;
```

to

```
java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: No problem! Please accept/upvote my answer to improve your approval rating so that in the future people will be more inclined to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

either import the class or import the whole package

1. Importing class

   `import java.util.Scanner;`

2.Importing the whole package

```
`import java.util.*;`
```

First will import only the selected class and the second will import all the classes in the package.